# Infinite self-joins in SQL with PHP?

Tags: php, sql, select

There is a SQL table like this:

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| ID | Comment   | ParentID |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Some Text |        0 |
|  2 | Some Text |        0 |
|  3 | Some Text |        2 |
|  4 | Some Text |        2 |
|  5 | Some Text |        3 |
|  6 | Some Text |        3 |
|  7 | Some Text |        1 |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

This are comments of a blog post and some child-comments. The depth of the child-level is infinite: every child-comment can have another child-comment.

A user wants to delete now his parent-comment with the ID 2. So i need a SQL query, which select all child-comment-IDs (and child-child-comments and so on).

Currently I have this query, which only selects the first level of the child comment:

```
SELECT ID
FROM comment_table
WHERE ParentID = 2
```

Is it possible to select *all* those child-comments in one query?

Comment: PHP can easily do this, but it'll have to be a series of separate queries to get each level. You don't say which DB you're on, but some DO support recursive queries, e.g. postgres, mssql. mysql notably does not.

Comment: I'm thinking a stored procedure, simply to do a DELETE on the current item each time it's called, and a recursive call on all rows associated with it, unless it's called with a NULL.

Comment: I'll point you to [MPTT](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/), a useful technique for dealing with exactly this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem and given your database structure doesn't really have a good answer, as most SQL databases don't support recursive queries, so you either need to do many, many queries (which is bad) or limit the nesting (also bad).

There are solutions but they involve alternate database schemas. Bill Karwin has written a fair bit about the issue of hierarchical data in PHP/MySQL. He has a talk available here: http://www.percona.tv/percona-webinars/models-for-hierarchical-data-in-sql-and-php where he discusses some options. He has also blogged and written chapter in his book (SQL Antipatterns) about the different options and their pros & cons.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in PHP with a simple recursive function:

```
function child_comments($id,&$arr) {
   $sql = 'SELECT ID, Comment, ParentID FROM comment_table WHERE ParentID='.$id;
   // get rows for $sql
   foreach ($rows as $row) {
      $arr[] = $row;
      child_comments($row['id'],$arr);
   }
}
child_comments(2,$comments);
```

`$comments` would hold an array of comment 2's children, it's children's children and so on...

The above code is meant to be taken as pseudo-code and would need adjusting to suit the way in which you are retrieving data from your database (pdo, mysqli, mysql_*).

In particular `// get rows for $sql` needs replacing with relevant code to fetch rows for the statement held in `$sql`.

The recursive call to `child_comments` may also need adjusting dependant on the structure of the rows returned from the database, `$row['id']` may not be the correct way of accessing the `ID` field.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this problem which I prefer to use is the addition of a "Materialized Path".

You just need to add a column which holds the entire ancestry of the object. For example, your table becomes adjusted like so:

```
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
| ID | Comment   | ParentID | TreePath |
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
|  1 | Some Text |        0 |          |
|  2 | Some Text |        0 |          |
|  3 | Some Text |        2 |       -2-|
|  4 | Some Text |        2 |       -2-|
|  5 | Some Text |        3 |     -2-3-|
|  6 | Some Text |        3 |     -2-3-|
|  7 | Some Text |        1 |       -1-|
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
```

Selecting all the descendants of 2 looks like this:

```
SELECT ID FROM comment_table WHERE TreePath LIKE '-2-%'
```

If you want to build a comment tree in PHP, you can even sort by `TreePath` to get an array that's fairly easy to convert to a tree.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno about a single query, but how about adding an isChildren column in that table?

That way you'll recieve the id of a comment to delete, store it in $idToDelete and delete the comment with id equal to the id you recieved, delete it, save its parentId in $idToDelete, etc. 
And you can do that within a while block that checks wether the column isChildren is true. If isChildren is false, then you deleted the first parent of that comment and all of its children.

That should work shouldn't it? Dunno if modifying the database is an option though.

Comment: Good idea, but i cant change the database structure.